# Windows phone 7 browser app crashing

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am fairly new to developing for windows mobile and am working to create a simple browser that can go to a site when a URL is input. I am working with a template that I got from
app-hub called mini browser which can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402526%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Unfortunately the web browser only seems to work when there is http:// infront of the url. For example the browser will go to http://www.google.com but crash when prompted to go to www.google.com . Is there any way I can get around this? As a learning developer, all thoughts and ideas with code needed if possible would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use relative Uri string (uri is relative when there is no http://, ftp:// or something like that in front of it) following code fragment from that tutorial will throw an exception:

```
new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute)
```

You can find more info about that constructor on MSDN: [Uri Constructor (String, UriKind)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131565.aspx)

I would suggest following change:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string site = textBox1.Text;
    try
    {    
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    catch(UriFormatException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("URL is not valid");
    }
}
```

This should prevent application from crashing when value inserted by user is now valid url